# When installing setup prerequisite is not asking for SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: .net, installation, sql-server-2008-express

I have an application which has SQL Server 2008 Express as a prerequisite. It is working fine on Windows XP and Windows 7 Home Basic. But when we install it on a Windows 7 Professional machine it asks for .Net framework but not ask for SQL Server 2008 Express.

I do not understand what is wrong in setup.

Comment: What are you using for your installer?  How are you installing it?  Access rights to the machine?  Are you installing as an admin?  Not really enough information here to solve your problem.

Comment: I am installing it as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Add/Remove and go to Windows Features.  You should find .Net there as an option.  You may also be able to use DISM to enable it via commandline:

```
Dism.exe /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3
```

Comment: You may need to, as @intracept mentioned, run command line under elevated or Administrator privileges.